# How to increase de volume of an interval of an mp3 file with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'd like to increase de volume of an interval of and mp3 file, i.e. from 20s to 30s increase in 15%. I'm using ffmpeg.

Thank you so much for your help!

Regards,

Raul.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -af volume=1.15:enable='between(t,20,30)' out.mp3
```